# Design: Product Treeview shared among several controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a product treeview that is referenced in multiple views and controller. The treeview items of the product treeview are loaded dynamically using AJAX and a public Action method.

Should i move the product treeview's logic and public action method to a shared controller such as SharedController? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

burnt1ce,

as ever, it depends... If you always use it via ajax (jquery or msajax?? [not that it matters much, but would allow you to add the appropriate tag to the question]), then I would be tempted to refactor it out to an html.helper with a few overloads  to allow different product models to be loaded. (I would recommend using product interfaces, rather than concrete classes to allow for a variety of product sub-classes if required)...

If you ever need to load it in the context of a view, then you could keep it where it is and load it via an html.RenderAction() method.

this would certainly be my initial thoughts.

Comment: where would you store the action method that responds to AJAX requests? There isn't much presentation logic to move to an HTML helper since i'm using Telerik's treeview control - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview.

Comment: ok, now that you've added the part about the treeview being a 3rd party telerik control, the situation changes. i thought you were rolling your own logic on this one, hence my comments above. if it's a 3rd party 'control', then i think you'll have to shout an ask on the telerik forums as i've got no experience in using any of the telerik mvc controls. sorry for the mis-understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A ProductController with the action to retrieve your product data (returns JSON?)

Use a Partial View to spell out the Telerik View.  I assume from that view you'll be making the ajax call to get the products then updating the treeview w/ that data?

```
<%= Html.Telerik().TreeView()
            .Name("TreeView")
            .Items(item =>
            {
                item.Add()
                    .Text("Mail")
                    .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mail.gif")
                    .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Mail Icon" })
                    .Items(subItem =>
                    {
...
```